# URL query is undefined when file exists on disk, but not otherwise

Tags: node.js

This is the  simplified version of what I have, but basically the same.

```
var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var pathname = url_parts.pathname;
var query = url_parts.query;
var datapath = "data_";
if(query.sort !== undefined)
    datapath += query.sort + ".json";


var file = fs.readFile(datapath, function(err,data) {
   if(err) throw err;
   jsondata = data.toString();
});
```

This works fine when the file does not exist in the directory. For example, calling http://localhost:12035/sort=date works fine if there is no "data_date.json". However, if that file does exist in the directory, "data_undefined.json" is used instead. Why is this? I have tried all kinds of workarounds to try and narrow it down (ie take a substring of just querystring.stringify(query) ) to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

You should really be checking if query.sort exists, because if I get http://localhost:12035/ query.sort will return "undefined".

Comment: I pared the code down to post this assuming that would work better for clarity. Sort is not undefined, except when the file exists in the directory...then somehow it goes from being defined in the url to no longer defined within the application.